# Setting global style in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there some way to set global styles in resource dictionary in xaml without having to specify any special settings in affected elements?

For example, let's say i have 
resdictionary.xaml file with

```
 <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

 </ResourceDictionary>
```

And then I have normal window.xaml file:

```
<Window x:Class="App.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="800" MinWidth="500" MinHeight="350">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="resdictionary.xaml" />
</Window.Resources>   

 <Button Content="Button 1"/>
 <Button Content="Button 2"/>
 <Button Content="Button 3"/>
 </Window>
```

And I want all buttons to have black-white background gradient and Calibri font.
Is there a way to specify this in the resdictionary.xaml without having to change the window.xaml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it the way *Dream Coder* has shown. But that way you have to set the `style` for every button. If you do not set the `style` to a button, that `button` will use the default windows style. To do so, you have to remove the `x:Key` from the `style`.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
             <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                     StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#000000" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF"
                      Offset="1" />
             </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" 
            Value="Calibri" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 5):

you can create a styles.xaml page and add all your styles there for example

```
<Style x:Key="SubmitButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Height">
        <Setter.Value>28px</Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Width">
        <Setter.Value>90px</Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness">
        <Setter.Value>1</Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>#000000</Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>#0073c6</Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" >
        <Setter.Value>Segoe UI</Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontSize">
        <Setter.Value>12px</Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

you can refer the styles.xaml in your windows using the following code.

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary  Source="../Resources/Styles.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

you can use the style in following way in your page

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource TelerikRadSubmitButtonStyle}"/>
```

hope this helps.